# Sublime Text is not converting tabs to spaces when indenting... why and how to fix it?

Tags: tabs, indentation, sublimetext, sublimetext3, spaces

I have been using quite effectively *Sublime text*. I have one problem that stil bugs me.

While I type JavaScript code the tabs not converted to spaces if *tab* is pressed additionally to the provided indentation level.

The following screenshot may help you in understanding my problem:

[image]

As you can see the initial level of indentation is correctly formatted as 8 spaces. If I press *tab* once again, then an actual tab charachter is inserted, instead of 4 spaces, as I would like.

The following is my User *Preferences.sublime-settings* configuration file:

```
{
"color_scheme": "Packages/User/Cobalt (SL).tmTheme",
"detect_indentation": false,
"expand_tabs_on_save": true,
"font_size": 10,
"ignored_packages":
[
    "Vintage"
],
"tab_size": 4,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
"trim_automatic_white_space": true,
"use_tab_stops": true,

// Calculates indentation automatically when pressing enter
"auto_indent": true,

// Makes auto indent a little smarter, e.g., by indenting the next line
// after an if statement in C. Requires auto_indent to be enabled.
"smart_indent": true,

// Adds whitespace up to the first open bracket when indenting. Requires
// auto_indent to be enabled.
"indent_to_bracket": false,

// Trims white space added by auto_indent when moving the caret off the
// line.
"trim_automatic_white_space": true,
```

}

The configuration seems to be set correctly. Any idea on why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: Hmm, as a quick sanity check, can you tell me the results of `view.settings().get("translate_tabs_to_spaces")`. Also, you have an extra comma in your preferences. ST handles it, but just thought I'd let you know if you didn't see it.

Comment: @skuroda, thanks for the suggestion. I am sorry but I will be back at work only this Friday. Then, I will try what you suggest and post back.

Comment: `view.settings().get("translate_tabs_to_spaces")` is returning `False`

Comment: So that means something is changing the setting in that file. It could be aplugin, or it could be a ST setting. Before we start working with plugins, try setting `detect_indentation` to `false` in your user preferences file.

Comment: `view.settings().get("detect_indentation")` is also returning `False`

Comment: Hmm well that's a bit disappointing (since I was hoping it would be an easy solution). In the bottom right corner, does it say "Spaces" or "Tabs"? Have you created any custom settings for JavaScript files? Can you list the plugins you have installed?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes smart_indent can mess up things. Try adding the following line to  Preferences>Settings-User

`"smart_indent": false`